# R: merging copies of the same variable

Tags: r, merge

I have data like this in R:

```
subjID = c(1,2,3,4)
var1 = c(3,8,NA,6)
var1.copy = c(NA,NA,5,NA)
fake = data.frame(subjID = subjID, var1 = var1, var1 = var1.copy)
```

which looks like this:

```
> fake
  subjID var1 var1.1
1      1    3     NA
2      2    8     NA
3      3   NA      5
4      4    6     NA
```

Var1 and Var1.1 represent the same variable, so each subject has NA for one column and a numerical value in the other (no one has two NAs or two numbers). I want to merge the columns to get a single Var1: (3, 8, 5, 6).

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use is.na, which can be vectorised as:

```
# get all the ones we can from var1
var.merged = var1;
# which ones are available in var1.copy but not in var1?
ind = is.na(var1) & !is.na(var1.copy);
# use those to fill in the blanks
var.merged[ind] = var1.copy[ind];
```

Comment: Elegant solution! Thank you. (I had to use square brackets in the last line, though, to prevent R from trying to call var.merged and var1.copy as functions.)

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I'm switching between R and MATLAB and my brain gets confused sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only dealing with two columns, and there are *never* two numbers or two NAs, you can calculate the row mean and ignore missing values:

```
fake$fixed <- rowMeans(fake[, c("var1", "var1.1")], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to merge if there are conflicts.

You could simply put *all* non-NA values in `var.1.1` into the corresponding slot of `var1`. In case of conflicts, this will favour `var.1.1`.

```
var1[!is.na(var1.copy)] <- var1.copy[!is.na(var1.copy)]
```

You could just fill in all NA values in `var1` with corresponding values of `var1.1`. In case of conflict, this will favour `var1`.

```
var1[is.na(var1)] <- var1.copy[is.na(var1)]
```