# merge/combine columns with same name but incomplete data

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames that have some columns with the same names and others with different names. The data frames look something like this:

```
df1
      ID hello world hockey soccer
    1  1    NA    NA      7      4
    2  2    NA    NA      2      5
    3  3    10     8      8     23
    4  4     4    17      5     12
    5  5    NA    NA      3     43

df2    
      ID hello world football baseball
    1  1     2     3       43        6
    2  2     5     1       24       32
    3  3    NA    NA        2       23
    4  4    NA    NA        5       15
    5  5     9     7       12       23
```

As you can see, in 2 of the shared columns ("hello" and "world"), some of the data is in one of the data frames and the rest is in the other.

What I am trying to do is (1) merge the 2 data frames by "id", (2) combine all the data from the "hello" and "world" columns in both frames into 1 "hello" column and 1 "world" column, and (3) have the final data frame also contain all of the other columns in the 2 original frames ("hockey", "soccer", "football", "baseball"). So, I want the final result to be this:

```
  ID hello world hockey soccer football baseball
1  1     2     3      7      4        43       6
2  2     5     3      2      5        24      32
3  3    10     8      8     23         2      23
4  4     4    17      5     12         5      15
5  5     9     7      3     43        12      23
```

I'm pretty new at R so the only codes I've tried are variations on `merge` and I've tried the answer I found here, which was based on a similar question: [R: merging copies of the same variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577264/r-merging-copies-of-the-same-variable). However, my data sets are actually much bigger than what I'm showing here (there's about 20 matching columns (like "hello" and "world") and 100s of non-matching ones (like "hockey" and "football")) so I'm looking for something that won't require me to write them all out manually.

Any idea if this can be done? I'm sorry I can't provide a sample of my efforts, but I really don't know where to start besides:

```
mydata <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("ID"), all = TRUE)
```

To reproduce the data frames:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), hellow = c(2, 5, NA, NA, 9), 
       world = c(3, 1, NA, NA, 7), football = c(43, 24, 2, 5, 12), 
       baseball = c(6, 32, 23, 15, 23)), .Names = c("ID", "hello", "world", 
       "football", "baseball"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)) 

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), hellow = c(NA, NA, 10, 4, NA), 
       world = c(NA, NA, 8, 17, NA), hockey = c(7, 2, 8, 5, 3), 
       soccer = c(4, 5, 23, 12, 43)), .Names = c("ID", "hello", "world", "hockey", 
       "soccer"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Is it always the case that if the value is `NA` in "df1" it would have a value in "df2" (and vice versa)?

Comment: Yes, that is always the case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an approach that involves `melt`ing your data, merging the molten data, and using `dcast` to get it back to a wide form. I've added comments to help understand what is going on.

```
## Required packages
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

dcast.data.table(
  merge(
    ## melt the first data.frame and set the key as ID and variable
    setkey(melt(as.data.table(df1), id.vars = "ID"), ID, variable), 
    ## melt the second data.frame
    melt(as.data.table(df2), id.vars = "ID"), 
    ## you'll have 2 value columns...
    all = TRUE)[, value := ifelse(
      ## ... combine them into 1 with ifelse
      is.na(value.x), value.y, value.x)], 
  ## This is your reshaping formula
  ID ~ variable, value.var = "value")
#    ID hello world football baseball hockey soccer
# 1:  1     2     3       43        6      7      4
# 2:  2     5     1       24       32      2      5
# 3:  3    10     8        2       23      8     23
# 4:  4     4    17        5       15      5     12
# 5:  5     9     7       12       23      3     43
```

Comment: One question: the values seem to come out non-numeric. Is there a way to accomplish this and keep them numeric?

Comment: yes, there are columns with character columns in my actual data but not in the columns I was having trouble merging. All of the columns that were melted seem to be character values now. Any way around this?

Comment: More specifically, I get this warning: `Warning message:
In melt.data.table(as.data.table(df2), id.vars = "id") :
  All 'measure.vars are NOT of the SAME type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'character'. Therefore all measure variables that are not of type 'character' will be coerced to.`

Answer (score 14):

Nobody's posted a `dplyr` solution, so here's a succinct option in `dplyr`. The approach is simply to do a `full_join` that combines all rows, then `group` and `summarise` to remove the redundant missing cells.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, hello = c(NA, NA, 10L, 4L, NA), world = c(NA, NA, 8L, 17L, NA), hockey = c(7L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 3L), soccer = c(4L, 5L, 23L, 12L, 43L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), hello = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), world = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), hockey = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), soccer = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, hello = c(2L, 5L, NA, NA, 9L), world = c(3L, 1L, NA, NA, 7L), football = c(43L, 24L, 2L, 5L, 12L), baseball = c(6L, 32L, 23L, 15L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), hello = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), world = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), football = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), baseball = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))

df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize_all(na.omit)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>      ID hello world hockey soccer football baseball
#>   <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>    <int>    <int>
#> 1     1     2     3      7      4       43        6
#> 2     2     5     1      2      5       24       32
#> 3     3    10     8      8     23        2       23
#> 4     4     4    17      5     12        5       15
#> 5     5     9     7      3     43       12        2
```

Created on 2018-07-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 6):

Here's another `data.table` approach using binary merge

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1), ID) ; setkey(setDT(df2), ID) # Converting to data.table objects and setting keys
df1 <- df1[df2][, `:=`(i.hello = NULL, i.world = NULL)] # Full left join
df1[df2[complete.cases(df2)], `:=`(hello = i.hello, world = i.world)][] # Joining only on non-missing values
#    ID hello world football baseball hockey soccer
# 1:  1     2     3       43        6      7      4
# 2:  2     5     1       24       32      2      5
# 3:  3    10     8        2       23      8     23
# 4:  4     4    17        5       15      5     12
# 5:  5     9     7       12       23      3     43
```

Answer (score 6):

@ananda-mahto 's answer is more elegant but here is my suggestion:

```
library(reshape2)
df1=melt(df1,id='ID',na.rm=TRUE)
df2=melt(df2,id='ID',na.rm=TRUE)
DF=rbind(df1,df2)
# Not needeed,  added na.rm=TRUE based on @ananda-mahto's valid comment
# DF<-DF[!is.na(DF$value),]
dcast(DF,ID~variable,value.var='value')
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated my answer to incorporate that. Yours is still more elegant :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more `tidyr` centric approach that does something similar to the currently accepted answer. The approach is simply to stack the data frames on top of each other with `bind_rows` (which matches column names), `gather` up all the non `ID` columns with `na.rm = TRUE`, and then `spread` them back out. This should be robust to situations where the condition "if the value is NA in "df1" it would have a value in "df2" (and vice versa)" doesn't always hold, compared to a `summarise` option.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, hello = c(NA, NA, 10L, 4L, NA), world = c(NA, NA, 8L, 17L, NA), hockey = c(7L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 3L), soccer = c(4L, 5L, 23L, 12L, 43L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), hello = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), world = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), hockey = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), soccer = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, hello = c(2L, 5L, NA, NA, 9L), world = c(3L, 1L, NA, NA, 7L), football = c(43L, 24L, 2L, 5L, 12L), baseball = c(6L, 32L, 23L, 15L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), hello = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), world = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), football = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), baseball = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))

df1 %>%
  bind_rows(df2) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  spread(variable, value)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>      ID baseball football hello hockey soccer world
#>   <int>    <int>    <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1     1        6       43     2      7      4     3
#> 2     2       32       24     5      2      5     1
#> 3     3       23        2    10      8     23     8
#> 4     4       15        5     4      5     12    17
#> 5     5        2       12     9      3     43     7
```

Created on 2018-07-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 5):

Using `tidyverse` we could use `coalesce`.

None of the solutions below builds extra rows, data stays more or less of the same size and similar shape throughout the chain.

**Solution 1**

```
list(df1,df2) %>%
  transpose(union(names(df1),names(df2))) %>%
  map_dfc(. %>% compact %>% invoke(coalesce,.))

# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#      ID hello world football baseball hockey soccer
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1     2     3       43        6      7      4
# 2     2     5     1       24       32      2      5
# 3     3    10     8        2       23      8     23
# 4     4     4    17        5       15      5     12
# 5     5     9     7       12       23      3     43
```

**Explanations**

- Wrap both data frames into a `list`
- `transpose` it, so each new item at the root has the name of a column of the output. Default behavior of `transpose` is to take the first argument as a template so unfortunately we have to be explicit to get all of them.
- `compact` these items, as they were all of length 2, but with one of them being `NULL` when the given column was missing on one side.
- `coalesce` those, which basically means return the first non `NA` you find, when putting arguments side by side.

if repeating `df1` and `df2` on the second line is an issue, use the following instead:

```
transpose(invoke(union, setNames(map(., names), c("x","y"))))
```

**Solution 2**

Same philosophy, but this time we loop on names:

```
map_dfc(set_names(union(names(df1), names(df2))),
        ~ invoke(coalesce, compact(list(df1[[.x]], df2[[.x]]))))

# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#      ID hello world football baseball hockey soccer
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1     2     3       43        6      7      4
# 2     2     5     1       24       32      2      5
# 3     3    10     8        2       23      8     23
# 4     4     4    17        5       15      5     12
# 5     5     9     7       12       23      3     43
```

Here it is once pipified for those who may prefer :

```
union(names(df1), names(df2)) %>%
  set_names %>%
  map_dfc(~ list(df1[[.x]], df2[[.x]]) %>%
            compact %>%
            invoke(coalesce, .))
```

**Explanations**

- `set_names` gives to character vector names identical to its values, so `map_dfc` can name the output's columns right.
- `df1[[.x]]` will return `NULL` when `.x` is not a column of `df1`, we take advantage of this.
- `df1` and `df2` are mentioned 2 times each and I can't think of any way around it.

Solution 1 is cleaner in respect to these points so I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

We could use my package *[safejoin](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin)*, do a left join and deal with the conflicts using `dplyr::coalesce`

```
# # devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)

safe_left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID", conflict = coalesce)
# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#      ID hello world hockey soccer football baseball
#   <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>    <int>    <int>
# 1     1     2     3      7      4       43        6
# 2     2     5     1      2      5       24       32
# 3     3    10     8      8     23        2       23
# 4     4     4    17      5     12        5       15
# 5     5     9     7      3     43       12        2
```

Comment: I am getting the same problem but I am looking for a solution in Python. Any help would be much appreciated!