# R dplyr full_join - no common key, need common columns to blend together

Tags: r, dplyr, outer-join

I have these two dataframes for example:

```
dates = c('2020-11-19', '2020-11-20', '2020-11-21')
df1 <- data.frame(dates, area = c('paris', 'london', 'newyork'), 
                  rating = c(10, 5, 6),
                  rating2 = c(5, 6, 7))

df2 <- data.frame(dates, area = c('budapest', 'moscow', 'valencia'), 
                  rating = c(1, 2, 1))
```

```
> df1
       dates    area rating rating2
1 2020-11-19   paris     10       5
2 2020-11-20  london      5       6
3 2020-11-21 newyork      6       7
> df2
       dates     area rating
1 2020-11-19 budapest      1
2 2020-11-20   moscow      2
3 2020-11-21 valencia      1
```

When performing an outer join using dplyr:

```
df <- df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = c('dates', 'area'))
```

the result is like this:

```
       dates     area rating.x rating2 rating.y
1 2020-11-19    paris       10       5       NA
2 2020-11-20   london        5       6       NA
3 2020-11-21  newyork        6       7       NA
4 2020-11-19 budapest       NA      NA        1
5 2020-11-20   moscow       NA      NA        2
6 2020-11-21 valencia       NA      NA        1
```

i.e. the rating columns from the two dataframes are not blended together but two separate columns are created.

How do I get a result like this?

```
       dates     area rating   rating2 
1 2020-11-19    paris       10       5       
2 2020-11-20   london        5       6       
3 2020-11-21  newyork        6       7       
4 2020-11-19 budapest        1      NA        
5 2020-11-20   moscow        2      NA        
6 2020-11-21 valencia        1      NA
```

Thanks to the solutions provided by @kybazzi, the desired result was obtained.

```
df <- df1 %>%
  bind_rows(df2)
```

**FOLLOW-UP**

As a follow-up question, I would like to join the following to the joined dataframe:

```
df3 <- data.frame(dates, area = c('budapest', 'moscow', 'valencia'), 
                  rating2 = c(3, 2, 5))
```

Using the same method, the result is this:

```
> df_final <- df %>%
+     bind_rows(df3)
> df_final
       dates     area rating rating2
1 2020-11-19    paris     10       5
2 2020-11-20   london      5       6
3 2020-11-21  newyork      6       7
4 2020-11-19 budapest      1      NA
5 2020-11-20   moscow      2      NA
6 2020-11-21 valencia      1      NA
7 2020-11-19 budapest     NA       3
8 2020-11-20   moscow     NA       2
9 2020-11-21 valencia     NA       5
```

How do i get a result like this:

```
       dates     area rating   rating2 
1 2020-11-19    paris       10       5       
2 2020-11-20   london        5       6       
3 2020-11-21  newyork        6       7       
4 2020-11-19 budapest        1       3        
5 2020-11-20   moscow        2       2        
6 2020-11-21 valencia        1       5
```

Comment: Are there any keys (e.g. city names) that *are* shared between the two data frames? This looks like you could specify rating2 = NA for df2 and use `rbind` to call it a day rather than fiddling with merges

Comment: potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167151/merge-combine-columns-with-same-name-but-incomplete-data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is `dplyr::bind_rows()`, which will preserve common columns and fill `NA` for columns that only exist in one of the data frames:

```
> bind_rows(df1, df2)
       dates     area rating rating2
1 2020-11-19    paris     10       5
2 2020-11-20   london      5       6
3 2020-11-21  newyork      6       7
4 2020-11-19 budapest      1      NA
5 2020-11-20   moscow      2      NA
6 2020-11-21 valencia      1      NA
```

Note that you could also continue using `full_join()` - but you must ensure that all common columns between the data frames are included as keys if you don't want columns to be split:

```
> full_join(
+   df1, df2,
+   by = c("dates", "area", "rating")
+ )
       dates     area rating rating2
1 2020-11-19    paris     10       5
2 2020-11-20   london      5       6
3 2020-11-21  newyork      6       7
4 2020-11-19 budapest      1      NA
5 2020-11-20   moscow      2      NA
6 2020-11-21 valencia      1      NA
```

The documentation for dplyr joins mentions:

> Output columns include all `x` columns and all `y` columns. If columns in `x` and `y` have the same name (and aren't included in `by`), suffixes are added to disambiguate.

You could also avoid this issue by not specifying `by`, in which case dplyr will use all common columns.

```
> full_join(df1, df2)
Joining, by = c("dates", "area", "rating")
       dates     area rating rating2
1 2020-11-19    paris     10       5
2 2020-11-20   london      5       6
3 2020-11-21  newyork      6       7
4 2020-11-19 budapest      1      NA
5 2020-11-20   moscow      2      NA
6 2020-11-21 valencia      1      NA
```

As far as I know, both methods are good for your use case. In fact, I believe that the practical advantage `full_join()` has over `bind_rows()` is precisely this behaviour you wanted to avoid here, i.e. splitting columns that aren't keys.

Comment: For anyone unable to find it, the `bind_rows` function comes from the `dplyr` package!

Comment: @kybazzi Always be sure to include all necessary libraries in your answer.